# Character limit for a cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

What is the character limit for a single cell in Google Sheets?

An answer in [this forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/aFvgNfRZQwI) mentioned it may be ~1 million.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While there may not have been a limit before when that forum was posted, today (July 2017) the limit is 50,000 characters. If you try to input 50,001 characters, you will get this error:

[image]

Comment: Anybody else instinctively try to click on "Ok" to make this dialog box go away?